# Grab Partial Character Array

Tags: c

I have a really long character array : `unsigned char hexs[50]`

If I print all the value using for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(hexs); i++)
        printf("%02x\n", hexs[i]);
```

It will give me bunch of value like:

```
2e
1e
a3
....
a1
```

If I only want to grab `2e and 1e`value into a new character array (ex: `unsigned char chosen_one[2]`), what should I do?

Comment: Do you want 1st and 2nd elements?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That is correct.

Comment: `memcpy(chosen_one, hexs, 2);`

Comment: If you really are only interested in the first two elements, then just assign the two values as `chosen_one[0] = hexs[0]; chosen_one[1] = hexs[1]`. If this needs to scale to different numbers other than two elements, then use `memcpy` as BLUEPIXY pointed out